# Disable mouse Drag to avoid scrolling

Tags: html, click, drag

I want to avoid click and drag functionality for the following scenario.

I have two DIVs

1. wrapper Div

   {
     width: 400px; 
     height:400px; 
     overflow-x: hidden;
   }
2. content div

   {
     width:1 200px; 
     height: 400px; /* note width is 3 times of wrapper div */
   }

content div is child of wrapper div.
wrapper div act as View Port only with in which I show content div.

When user click on button I set scroll position to show proper part of content div with in wrapper.(0-400, 401-800, 801-1200)
But if a user clicks and drags the mouse pointer then wrapper div gets scrolled(because of dragging). I want to avoid this scrolling on click and drag.

I have tried the following things :

```
var isMouseDown = false;
function onmousedown(event) {
    isMouseDown = true;
}

function onmouseup(event) {
    isMouseDown = false;
}

function onmousemove(event) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        event.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Above code doesn't help me.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably if you use the arrows on your keyboard you can also scroll, also pressing the spacebar will cause the screen to scroll. You may want to check these before only tackling scroll using highlighting/dragging.

Comment: Its not vertical scroll. Also scroll bar is not visible since overflow-x is hidden. Hence arrow keys and space doesn't move screen left and right. but when you click and drag that time scrolling occurs. where screen is partially shifted which is annoying in my UI.

Answer (score 0):

I check when wrapper div get scroll.

I added event "onscroll" and set one global variable "shouldScroll" to true when button is click and set it to false when div get scroll to required position.

When user click and drag mouse, wrapper div scroll event get fired but I check if "shouldScroll" is true then only allow scroll otherwise scroll to current position.

On button click I set current scroll position in one global variable.